# Can the select function be used in windows for input with timeout?

Tags: c++, c, windows, input

[The windows documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx) only mentions the select function using sockets, but the [GNU C documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html) mentions that it can be used for any input file descriptor.

Can the select function be used in windows for input from stdin?

Here is a simple program written using the C select function that I can compile with gcc

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <sys/types.h>

int input_timeout (int filedes, unsigned int seconds)
{
    fd_set set;
    struct timeval timeout;

    /* Initialize the file descriptor set. */
    FD_ZERO (&set);
    FD_SET (filedes, &set);

    /* Initialize the timeout data structure. */
    timeout.tv_sec = seconds;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    /* select returns 0 if timeout, 1 if input available, -1 if error. */
    return select (filedes + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
}

int
main (void)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "select returned %d.\n", input_timeout (fileno(stdin), 5));
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a very similar program written for windows that compiles with CL

```
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <sys/types.h>


int input_timeout (int filedes, unsigned int seconds)
{
    struct fd_set set;
    struct timeval timeout;

    /* Initialize the file descriptor set. */
    FD_ZERO (&set);
    FD_SET (filedes, &set);

    /* Initialize the timeout data structure. */
    timeout.tv_sec = seconds;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    /* select returns 0 if timeout, 1 if input available, -1 if error. */
    return select (filedes + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
}

int
main (void)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "select returned %d.\n", input_timeout (_fileno(stdin), 5));
    return 0;
}
```

The first works as expected, returning a 1 if theres input, a 0 if it times out

The second always returns -1

Comment: C != C++. Please only tag with the language you're actually using, in the future.

Comment: No.  On Windows, select() can only be used on sockets.

Comment: The sockets also have to be from a single provider, for which its [`WSPSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736553) is called. Commonly the provider is mswsock.dll, which talks to the AFD device (ancillary function driver). In this case sockets are kernel handles, so it's doubly wrong to pass a CRT file descriptor.

Comment: @ScottM Your code is using C++ headers, but is written as if you were using C. You should fix that, by either actually writing idiomatic C++ or fixing the headers to use C headers.

Comment: @tambre so this is a simple example that I wrote for the purposes of this post, the place where this will be used in a more C++ specific context. I wasn't sure if there would be any differences between the two languages and if there were any C++ gotchas I wanted to know. 

You mentioned idiomatic C++, but I figured for an example this simple there wouldn't be any differences between how it's written in C++ vs C. What would have been the idiomatic C++ way?

Comment: @eryksun, is there any cross platform method for getting input with a timeout in C++? I managed to get it working for windows using windows input and the WaitForSingleObject function, but it'd be nice if there was some standard library that Microsoft and the GNU world both accepted

Comment: The closest I was able to come to a cross-platform method was to hide the implementation behind a C++ object that provides a file-descriptor to pass to select() -- in the non-Windows implementation, it just provides STDIN_FILENO; in the Windows implementation, it provides a TCP socket that is one end of a connection to an internal thread that is reading from stdin and writing the stdin-data to the other end of the connection.  (this was a pain to implement, but at least now I have a single non-blocking-read-from-stdin API that works the same on all OS's)

Comment: @ScottM Well, if you're willing to wait a few years, then C++20 should have networking in the standard library. I personally use a wrapper object for a socket, but write platform-specific code for more advanced operations, such as waiting for data to arrive.

Comment: @ScottM That said, in C++ you should always use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. Additionally, you don't have to add `void` to the arguments, if the function has none - `int main(void)` and `int main()` are equivalent in C++. Furthermore, since you use standard C++ headers (which you should), all the standard library functions, such as `fprintf` are only guaranteed to be available in the `std` namespace. Those changes would make your code be much more idiomatic C++-like. And if you do make thse changes (you should), then it's probably a good idea to remove the C tag, as it won't compile as C.